# operator does not exist integer : refcursor, 42883 | Postgres

Tags: postgresql, cursor

I have to delete records from 3 table. The condition for deleting from 3rd table(Parent table) is that it should only be deleted if there exist no child record for it. I am using cursor and trying to delete from the tables using cursor. I am trying to execute function but I am facing the error mentioned in title. Below is my code :-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION housekeeping(
   OUT p_message_out CHARACTER VARYING,
   OUT p_sqlstate_out CHARACTER VARYING
   )
   RETURNS RECORD AS 
$BODY$

DECLARE 
v_msg CHARACTER VARYING(160);
v_sqlstate CHARACTER VARYING(6);
v_id INTEGER;
c_del CURSOR FOR SELECT employee_id FROM notification WHERE  sys_time<=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30 Days';
v_del REFCURSOR;

BEGIN

OPEN c_del;
LOOP
FETCH c_del INTO v_del;
EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
delete from client where payment_id in(select payment_id from notification where sys_time<=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30 Days');

delete from notification where sys_time<=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30 Days';

select count(*) into v_id from notification where employee_id=v_del;
IF v_id=0 THEN
delete from employee where employee_id=v_del;
END IF;
END LOOP;

v_msg = 'Data deleted successfully.';
v_sqlstate = 1; 

p_message_out = v_msg;
p_sqlstate_out = v_sqlstate;

--Exception handling
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
p_message_out=SQLERRM;
p_sqlstate_out=SQLSTATE;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
```

Comment: But v_id is used for counting the rows in notification table if there any exist or not. If rows doesnt exist then need to proceed with deletion. Also it may contain multiple employee id. Hence we are using cursor. PLease correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for loops or even variables to do that.

You can use a co-related sub-query to conditionally delete the employees at the end.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION housekeeping
   (
     OUT p_message_out CHARACTER VARYING,
     OUT p_sqlstate_out CHARACTER VARYING
   )
   RETURNS RECORD AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
  delete from client 
  where payment_id in (select payment_id 
                       from notification 
                       where sys_time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30 Days');

  delete from notification 
  where sys_time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30 Days';

  -- delete all employees for which no notification exists
  delete from employee emp
  where not exists (select *
                    from notification n
                    where n.employee_id = emp.employee_id);

  p_message_out  := 'Data deleted successfully.';
  p_sqlstate_out := 1; 

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  --Exception handling
  p_message_out := SQLERRM;
  p_sqlstate_out := SQLSTATE;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You're a bravo!!!!!!!!!!!
I want to learn cursor with different examples. Could you please suggest me some links.

Comment: @Nik: any time you are thinking "cursors" or "loops" with a relational database: re-think. That is not the natural approach to do things. A set-based approach is almost always the better choice. Rather than focusing on "learning cursors", you should learn how to apply set-based solutions.